# How can I update a specific column in my gridview after a timed event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web app I have a `GridView` that gets information from the SQL database then I have a timed event that pings the IP addresses every 5 seconds.  If the response is less that 15ms the icon is displayed as a green tick.  If more that 15ms the icon changes to a yellow exclamation mark, and when timed out a red error icon.

The code is working like it should(regarding the timed event), however the icon doesn't get replaced according to the timed response instead it adds a new icon every time

for example:

if the time is less that 15ms on first timed event:

```
 Y
```

if the time is more than 15 ms on second timed event:

```
 Y !
```

As you can see the `Y` remains whereas it should then just display the `!`

This is my code (aspx)

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:constr %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT ip, host, device FROM [servers]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:Timer runat="server" ID="UpdateTimer" Interval="5000" OnTick="UpdateTimer_Tick" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="TimedPanel" updatemode="Conditional">
         <triggers>
             <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="UpdateTimer" eventname="Tick" />
                 </triggers>
                  <ContentTemplate>
                   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="gridview" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"
                                                AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="ip" Width="100%">
                   <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AltRow"></AlternatingRowStyle>
                     <Columns>
                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" Visible="False" ImageUrl="~/Images/green.png" />
                                <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" Visible="False" ImageUrl="~/Images/red.png" />
                                <asp:Image ID="Image5" runat="server" Visible="False" ImageUrl="~/Images/yellow.png" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                     <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                         <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                           </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ip" HeaderText="IP Address" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="host" HeaderText="Host Name" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="device" HeaderText="Description" />
                      </Columns>
                     </asp:GridView>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

For the code behind:

```
 protected void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Servers();
    }

 private void Servers()
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Image Image3 = (Image)row.FindControl("Image3");
                Image Image4 = (Image)row.FindControl("Image4");
                Image Image5 = (Image)row.FindControl("Image5");
                TimedPanel.Update();
                string destIP = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Ping p = new Ping();
                        PingReply reply;
                        reply = p.Send(destIP);

                        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                        {
                            if (reply.RoundtripTime > 15)
                            {
                                Image5.Visible = true;
                                Image5.ToolTip = Convert.ToString("RoundTripTime: " + reply.RoundtripTime + "ms");
                            }

                            else
                                Image3.Visible = true;
                                Image3.ToolTip = Convert.ToString("RoundTripTime: " + reply.RoundtripTime + "ms");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Image4.Visible = true;
                            Image4.ToolTip = reply.Status.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (PingException err)
                    {
                        Image4.ToolTip = err.Message.ToString();
                        Image4.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What I have tried was to update the panel by using:

```
TimedPanel.Update();
```

This didn't work though.  Obviously when I refresh the entire page then it works but don't want to do that.  I am also not sure if one can update just the column where the icons are being displayed after each timed event.

Any suggestions on how I get the icons to display one at a time after the timed event?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have resolved the issue.

1. Remove the Images from the `ItemTemplate` and add a panel

   ```
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel4"></asp:Panel>
   </ItemTemplate>
   ```
2. Change the code behind to

   ```
   Image Image2 = new Image();
   Image Image3 = new Image();
   Image Image4 = new Image();
   Panel serverPanel = (Panel)row.FindControl("Panel4");
   ```
3. Add the images like this:

   ```
    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                        {
                            if (reply.RoundtripTime > 50)
                            {
                                Image2.ImageUrl = "../Images/yellow.png";
                                serverPanel.Controls.Add(Image2);
                                Image2.ToolTip = Convert.ToString("RoundTripTime: " + reply.RoundtripTime + "ms");
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                Image3.ImageUrl = "../Images/green.png";
                                serverPanel.Controls.Add(Image3);
                                Image3.ToolTip = Convert.ToString("RoundTripTime: " + reply.RoundtripTime + "ms");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Image4.ImageUrl = "../Images/red.png";
                            serverPanel.Controls.Add(Image4);
                            Image4.ToolTip = reply.Status.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (PingException err)
                    {
                        Image4.ImageUrl = "../Images/red.png";
                        serverPanel.Controls.Add(Image4);
                        Image4.ToolTip = err.Message.ToString();
                    }
   ```

so it will then be:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server"
         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:constr %>"
          SelectCommand="SELECT ip, host, device FROM [addfirewall]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
       <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="UpdateTimer3" Interval="5000" OnTick="UpdateTimer3_Tick" />
          <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel3" UpdateMode="Conditional">
              <ContentTemplate>
                   <asp:GridView ID="GridView4" CssClass="gridview" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"
                                                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" DataKeyNames="ip" Width="100%">
                     <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AltRow"></AlternatingRowStyle>
            <Columns>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel4"></asp:Panel>
                </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
              <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="ip" HeaderText="IP Address" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="host" HeaderText="Host Name" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="device" HeaderText="Description" />
            </Columns>
         </asp:GridView>
       </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateTimer3" EventName="Tick" />
     </Triggers>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
  private void Servers()
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView4.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                Image Image2 = new Image();
                Image Image3 = new Image();
                Image Image4 = new Image();
                Panel serverPanel = (Panel)row.FindControl("Panel4");
                string destIP = GridView4.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Ping p = new Ping();
                        PingReply reply;
                        reply = p.Send(destIP);

                        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                        {
                            if (reply.RoundtripTime > 50)
                            {
                                Image2.ImageUrl = "../Images/yellow.png";
                                serverPanel.Controls.Add(Image2);
                                Image2.ToolTip = Convert.ToString("RoundTripTime: " + reply.RoundtripTime + "ms");
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                Image3.ImageUrl = "../Images/green.png";
                                serverPanel.Controls.Add(Image3);
                                Image3.ToolTip = Convert.ToString("RoundTripTime: " + reply.RoundtripTime + "ms");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Image4.ImageUrl = "../Images/red.png";
                            serverPanel.Controls.Add(Image4);
                            Image4.ToolTip = reply.Status.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (PingException err)
                    {
                        Image4.ImageUrl = "../Images/red.png";
                        serverPanel.Controls.Add(Image4);
                        Image4.ToolTip = err.Message.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```